# dynamic page is not working

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have created a controller named index and I want to develop dynamic controllers like it is a big hurdle to creating page name again and again so i decided to create but i have some confusion about it though how I will developing the pages as I have placed an option in the admin panel like users can create pages though but the big issue is that I am unable to retrive that pages.

Controller

```
public function index($page = 7) {
        //$page = 7 where 7 is the default page set for home 
        $page_data           = $this->get_data->AllData('pages', $page);
        $data['title']   = $page_data->row()->pagetitle;
        $class               = explode("/", $page_data->row()->template);
        $data['body_class'] = $class[1];

        $this->load->view('includes/header.php', $data);

        if($class[1] == 'home') {
            $this->load->view('templates/slider');
        }

        $this->load->view('templates/navigation.php');

        $page_content   = $page_data->row()->template;
        $this->load->view($page_content, $data);
        $this->load->view('includes/footer.php');
    }

    public function page($pagename) {
        $page_data          = $this->get_data->AllData('pages', $pagename);
        $data['title']      = $page_data->row()->pagetitle;
        $class              = explode("/", $page_data->row()->template);
        $data['body_class'] = $class[1];

        $this->load->view('includes/header.php', $data);

        if($class[1] == 'home') {
            $this->load->view('templates/slider');
        }

        $this->load->view('templates/navigation.php');

        if($class[1] == 'home') {
            $data['slider'] = 'templates/slider';
        }

        $data['content']    = $page_data->row()->template;
        $this->load->view('index', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer-form.php');
        $this->load->view('includes/footer.php');
    }
```

Model

```
public function AllData($table, $pageid) {
    $query_data = $this->db->get_where($table, array('pageid' => $pageid));
    return $query_data;
}
```

My navigation page

```
 <?php
      $sql_nav = $this->db->get("menu_navigation");
       foreach($sql_nav->result() as $nav) {
                        echo "<li><a href='".base_url()."home/page/".$nav->menu_name."'>".$nav->$menu_name."</a></li>";
                        //output will be http://localhost:90/kwikrepair/home/page/(menu name which is the page name exist in the database)
                    }
                ?>
```

Now I am trying to send a call to the pages of requested data that is coming from the pages so like page data will be call upon when users click on the navigation and the the page id i want to pass in as a parameter to the index controller that how it will be passed ?

Comment: you want to develop dynamic pages? are you sure? ok you seem sincere so here you go: http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/tutorial/index.html

Comment: :) Yes i am trying to develop my own cms where we can develop pages like we do in wordpress

Comment: can you please tell me what is your link url on navigation page

Comment: see my updated question

Comment: value of `$nav->page_link` ? give me a sample output of your full link.

Comment: http://localhost:90/kwikrepair/home/page/get-a-quote this is the out put working fine with page controller which i have created a new one let me post that as i changed my navigatiion structure now working fine for me but the structure seems to be very ugly i am thinking to make it like this 
http://localhost:90/kwikrepair/get-a-quote let me update my question and include the page function with updated menu navigation

Comment: Please check the question now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't the correct way to develop dynamic pages using Codeigniter. Codeigniter is an MVC framework. If you follow the proper seperation of Model-View-Controller, it is very easy to develop dynamic web pages using codeigniter.

Codeigniter user guide is very easy to follow and has good examples. Please try to do some of those given tutorials.

In codeigniter, the views are loaded in the order they appear in controller.
Like:

```
$this->load->view('header');
$this->load->view('body');
$this->load->view('footer');
```

So if you want to optionally load a page segment, do in controller:

```
if($class[1] == 'home') {
    $this->load->view('templates/slider');
}
```

You don't pass a view inside a variable. Its for passing data that you get from the database model.
To pass any data to a view, do:

```
$data['title'] = "some title" //any data or variable
```

Then you can pass data to its associated view like:

```
$this->load->view('my_view',$data);
```

and you will be able to view the title as a $title variable in my_view.

Similarly you can save navigation template in views/templates folder
and load it as:

```
$this->load->view('templates/navigation');
```

You don't do:

```
<?php include('templates/navigation.php'); ?>
```

like with normal php pages. Codeigniter is an MVC web framework. Follow the proper MVC guidelines as described in the codeigniter's excellent user guide documentation.

Default format of Codeigniter URLs is like:

```
<installation-folder>/index.php/<controller>/<function>
```

If I have a controller named Welcome.php like:

```
class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

    /**
     * Index Page for this controller.
     *
     * Maps to the following URL
     *      http://example.com/index.php/welcome
     *  - or -
     *      http://example.com/index.php/welcome/index
     *  - or -
     * Since this controller is set as the default controller in
     * config/routes.php, it's displayed at http://example.com/
     *
     * So any other public methods not prefixed with an underscore will
     * map to /index.php/welcome/<method_name>
     * @see https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('welcome_message');
    }

    public function display($Page = 7){
        echo $Page;
    }
}
```

I can go to the page:

```
http://127.0.0.1/CI/index.php/welcome/display
```

and I will be shown 7, as it is the default value assigned to $Page variable if we don't pass it anything.

If we go to:

```
http://127.0.0.1/CI/index.php/welcome/display/2
```

$Page variable will get assigned the value 2 and it will display 2.

Here are the comments taken from default controller that comes with Codeigniter installation:

```
/**
 * Index Page for this controller.
 *
 * Maps to the following URL
 *      http://example.com/index.php/welcome
 *  - or -
 *      http://example.com/index.php/welcome/index
 *  - or -
 * Since this controller is set as the default controller in
 * config/routes.php, it's displayed at http://example.com/
 *
 * So any other public methods not prefixed with an underscore will
 * map to /index.php/welcome/<method_name>
 * @see https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html
 */
```

Comment: thank you i refered to the tutorial but there is not documnetation about the url like creating navigation let suppose I have passed a parameter as index($page = 'home') now how will i place in the link like user clicks on about page how come i will pass it on the navigation ? and also if the page name is in database so how will i pass it to my controller as a parameter?

Comment: please check the updated code in my question where i am passing page id as a parameter and that page id is calling by the navigation

Comment: perfect that sounds great to me now if I am going ad typing the url as http://localhost:90/kwikrepair/home/8 it is giving me as The page you requested was not found. and if i type in as http://localhost:90/kwikrepair/ showing yes the default page with an id of 7 so it means that it is not getting the correct page but this page exist

Comment: wow i am amazed i created new controller named page and when i make a call as localhost:90/kwikrepair/home/page/8 it is working fine I am surprised why is this happening is something I am missing ?

Comment: Its not http://localhost:90/kwikrepair/home/8 ; it should be http://localhost:90/kwikrepair/home/index/8. You forgot to include function name in URL